# Drupal - Overriding a existing module's hook?

Tags: drupal, module, hook

I need to override the 'node' module's 'node_search' hook in my custom module named 'tester'. I am trying to write the hook in tester.module with the name - tester_node_search, but it just would not work.

I have searched a lot over the internet but am not able to find any concrete solution. Can somebody please help...

Answer (score 1):

the hook is named hook_search, so your module function should be "tester_search" instead of "tester_node_search".